# I have 3 fields validating correctly. The submissions post to a text file correctly. However

Tags: php

I have 3 fields validating correctly. The submissions post to a text file correctly. However, they post  - - (as I have in the code to separate each section) even when the submit button is clicked without filling in the information.  There should not be any empty information with just 2 - - printed to the text file without filling in the 3 fields first. How can I fix that?  Sorry for the inconvenience, I answered my own question in another post and was able to fix the problem.  Thank you for your time.

Here is my code

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['website'])) {
        if(empty($_POST['name'])) {
            $errors[] = "Name is required";
        } else{
            $name = htmlentities($_POST['name']);
            $name = test_input($_POST['name']);
            if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
                $errors[] = "Only letters and white space allowed for the name";
            }
        }
        if(empty($_POST['email'])) {
            $errors[] = "Please provide your Email address.";
        } else if(filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ===       
    false){
            $errors[] = "Your Email is not valid.";
        } else {
            $email = htmlentities($email);
        }
        if(empty($_POST['website'])) {
            $errors[] = "Please provide your company URL.";
        } else{
            $website = htmlentities($_POST['website']);
            $website = test_input($_POST['website']);
            if(!preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",$website)) {
                $errors[] = "Please provide a valid URL for your company.";
            }
        }
    } 

    function test_input($data) {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;
    }

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $website = $_POST['website'];
    $data = $name . " - " . $email . " - " . $website;
    $file = "textfile.txt";

    if($_POST){
        file_put_contents($file, $data . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
    }
?>
```

In the html I have

```
    <?php
    if(empty($errors) === false){
    ?>
    <ul>
    <?php
    foreach($errors as $error){
    echo "<li>",$error,"</li>";
    }
    ?>
    </ul>
    <?php
    }else{
    if(isset($name, $email, $website)){
    echo "<b>Thank you for your submission.</b>"; 
    } 
    }
    ?> 
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper w3-round-xlarge">
    <div class="formtitle w3-round-xlarge">Thank you for filling in all fields below
    </div>
    <div class="formwrapper w3-round-xlarge">
    <form name="mobile" id="mobile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="data.php"><br/>
```

etc. (the html document starts and ends correctly. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If all three inputs are required them, place required into the html input.

```
<Input name="email" required />
```

Do this for each input. This will not allow for the form to be processed until all fields are filed.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to inconvenience anyone for taking the time to read my post. I was able to fix the problem simply by removing the following from the php code above my html and changing the following

```
    if($_POST){
    file_put_contents($file, $data . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
    }

    to ... 
    <?php
    }else{
    if(isset($name, $email, $website)){
    file_put_contents($file, $data . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
    echo "<b>Your submission has been sent.</b>"; 
    } 

    and adding it to the html div area
```